# StackOverflowException Error

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, stack-overflow

I’m having an issue where I have put in my first array to a public method called DisplayArray1(), I have compiled it and when I got to open up the executable file is says “Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException”? Has anyone else had this problem?

This is my code so far:

```
using System;

namespace FlexibleArrayMethod
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Clear();

            // Call intDisplayArray1() to output on screen
            intDisplayArray1();
            Console.Write("Array 1:  ");
        }
        public static int intDisplayArray1()
        {
            // first array declaration
            int[] Array1 = {5, 10, 15, 20};

            return intDisplayArray1[];
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: how did you compile this? `return intDisplayArray1[];` is not valid.

Comment: also can you explain what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I imagine your real code is `return intDisplayArray1();` but it looks like you meant `return Array1;`.

Comment: I compiled everything through Command line. No errors came up while compiling either so I'm honestly not sure if you're saying it isn't valid. I trying to create a console-based application that declares 3 arrays of different sizes. Then passes each array to a method that displays all the integers in each array and their sum.

Comment: @AlyBee i liked your comment because you honestly said what you want. :-)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary thank you xD I'm honestly struggling right now in my Programming 1 class and I can explain what I need it to do, I'm just unsure of how to get the outcome correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that `return intDisplayArray1[];` (which doesn't compile) is really `return intDisplayArray1();` in your code, you are in a recursive loop.

You are calling your method repeatedly without an exit condition.  Looks like you really just want to return your array:

```
 public static int[] intDisplayArray1()
 {
    int[] Array1 = { 5, 10, 15, 20 };

    return Array1;
 }
```

though there are a profound amount of logical errors still.

Here's what I'm led to believe you are trying to do:

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.Clear();

    // Call intDisplayArray1() to output on screen
    int[] array1 = intDisplayArray1();
    Console.Write("Array 1: " + string.Join(",", array1));
    Console.Read();
}

public static int[] intDisplayArray1()
{
   // first array declaration
   int[] Array1 = { 5, 10, 15, 20 };

   return Array1;
}
```

Comment: I edited the code and it shows the `Console.Write("Array 1:  ");` in the command line, but my array itself doesn't show

Comment: I'll go ahead and post the entirety of what I believe you are wanting

Comment: @AlyBee dont expect when you compile `Console.Write("Give me coffee: ");` actually do what you want.

Comment: So then I should just put `Console.Write(intDisplayArray());`?

Comment: you certainly could try it and find out what it does.  Best way to learn.

Comment: @Jonesopolis Honestly, I'm not advanced enough to understand the `Console.Write("Array 1: " + string.Join(",", array1));` part. I get declaring `intDisplayArray1()` as `int[] array1`, though.

Comment: Microsoft puts out documentation for us -> [string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Oh, okay, I get it now! So, with the other arrays I have to implement and adding them together is the other issue. Now knowing how to display each one on the screen should resolve displaying the sum as well. Adding them will be the next hurtle to get over.

Comment: i think first you have to learn more about arrays. the way you just wanted to try `Console.Write(intDisplayArray());` will just print `System.Int32[]`. Thats right. the type of `int[]`. but in order to print elements of array you have to write  `Console.Write(array[0]);` and it will print first element. then `Console.Write(array[1]);` will print second element. this can be done inside loop though. @AlyBee

Comment: I appreciate all the help, guys :) You're angels! <3

Comment: So, update: The code works and I have all my arrays listed in their own methods and displayed in the Main method. Now I'm trying to calculate the sum of all of them. Any tips?

Comment: the sum of every number in every array?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Like, I've displayed array1 and now I need to display the sum of that array and so on. It's not requesting to add all the arrays together.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Array 1 Total: " + array1.Sum());`, you might need to add a using  statement for`System.Linq`

Comment: This may sound like a stupid question, but what exactly does that mean?